# How to properly connect QPushButton clicked signal to pyqtSlot

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm writing a tool with GUI, where I inevitably need to use `pyqtSlot`. I had errors in this tool, related to its usage and decided to try a minimal example. However, I still fail to figure out the problem.

I've read instructions [here](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-buttons/). My findings for creation of a custom slot for a pushbutton were the following:

1. In a class, defining my GUI, I need to create a method, decorated as `@pyqtSlot()`;
2. I need to write something like `self.mybtn.connect(self.<method name>)` after button creation.

So, I created a UI in QtDesigner, compiled it and came up with the following code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.react_to_signal)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def react_to_signal(self):
        print("Button press signal emitted")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, when this code is run, it fails for me with the following error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect QPushButton::clicked(bool) to (nullptr)::react_to_signal()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<mypath>/ui_test_slots.py", line 36, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  File "<mypath>/ui_test_slots.py", line 15, in setupUi
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.react_to_signal)
TypeError: connect() failed between clicked(bool) and react_to_signal()
```

Other questions I saw on SO for this problem were caused by usage of the decorated method as a class method, no an instance method. But this doesn't seem to be my case.

What am I missing? What are the real differences between the example I referred to and my code?

Comment: 1. `pyqt*` decorators only work for QObject subclasses: `Ui_MainWindow` is a basic python object; 2. the `pyqtSlot` decorator is actually rarely required, and its usage is only suggested for very specific situations (eg. dealing with complex multithreading, developing a Designer plugin or having *thousands* of QObjects);  3. as the header of that pyuic file warns about, you should not edit those files unless you know what you're doing, so please regenerate that file and properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante, Thank you for highlighting that I can't use slots in plain objects. 1. I really DO need slots, since I have multithreading with custom data exchange between threads via signals and slots. 2. I mentioned using Designer only as a proof of validity of other code written except decorated function and `connect` statement. I know what I'm doing there and why, 3. If I subclass `Ui_MainWindow` from `QObject`, this solves the problem. Do you see any downsides in that solution?

Comment: What's more, the question, you've linked mine to as a duplicate is completely unrelated to the signal-slot issue this question is about. The issue in this question has completely nothing to do with Designer. If you put the part, regarding `QObjects`, as an answer or find the question which really IS related to the problem of sibnals and slots (not Designer), I'll upvote or accept duplication. For now I'm editing this question to re-open it

Comment: 1. The threading requirement is not necessarily related to the usage of Qt slots (unless you consider [this case](//stackoverflow.com/a/20818401)): what normally matters is the *thread affinity* of the method that is connected to the signal; if the slot is a method of a standard QThread (running its event loop), then things *may* change, but since you're not using a QObject at all, that means that it will always be run in the caller's thread; 2. Sorry to be blunt, but if you *knew* what you were doing, you were not trying to use the `pyqtSlot` decorator in a object that is not a QObject; ->

Comment: -> There's nothing wrong about using Designer, but using a pyuic class as an example for it shows that you don't know QObjects and their slot requirements; 3. There is really no point in making a pyuic class inherit from QObject, since those classes are *not* meant to be used like that: while nothing technically forbids you to do that, they're only intended as helper classes (they could just be functions, having them as classes allows proper multiple inheritance, allowing `self.setupUi(self)`). Having a *further* class/instance is completely pointless for this: it's done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Finally, yes, your question *is* a duplicate, because if you properly used a QWidget subclass (as explained in the guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)) you'd have had no problem in using that slot decorator (as your attempt in changing the inheritance shows): you'd have used a QMainWindow subclass, and being it a QObject (all QWidgets inherit from it) that would have allowed the `pyqtSlot()` without arguments, even if the signals provides one. That answer may not be an *exact* duplicate, but the cause of the problem is still the same.

Comment: @musicamante, Ok, thank you. Now I see what you meant. Dunning–Kruger effect at its best. It's ok to be blunt for as long as you provide arguments for this, which now you've excessively provided

Comment: Much love for the Dunning-Kruger reference and that "excessively" (which is perfectly right and I really appreciate it: I know I'm pedantic :-) ) I sincerely hope that my comments help you: while it certainly is not perfect (and it couldn't), Qt is an incredibly wonderful toolkit, but its complexity is often underestimated, especially from beginners; but, believe me, that mistake is not exclusive to them: even after using it for years, there are still times when I'm humbly surprised by some of its aspects, and I know I'm not alone... Good luck, and happy coding! :-)